# NSArray index beyond bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, indexing, nsarray

I think I'm going mad on something simple.

The following code:

```
        NSLog(@"potentialPositions: %@, with count: %i", potentialPositions, [potentialPositions count]);

    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < (choices); i++) {
        NSLog(@"i = %i",i);
        [self drawAWord:[[currentLevel objectAtIndex:levelLink] objectAtIndex:i] atPoint:[[potentialPositions objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue] withInitialZoom:FALSE];
    }
```

Produces the following result:

```
2014-02-15 20:31:54.329 ThesaurusLinks[12446:70b] potentialPositions: (
"NSPoint: {180, 125}",
"NSPoint: {270, 200}",
"NSPoint: {350, 250}",
"NSPoint: {280, 160}"
), with count: 4
2014-02-15 20:31:54.330 ThesaurusLinks[12446:70b] i = 1
2014-02-15 20:31:54.331 ThesaurusLinks[12446:70b] i = 2
2014-02-15 20:31:54.331 ThesaurusLinks[12446:70b] i = 3
2014-02-15 20:31:54.334 ThesaurusLinks[12446:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

There are clearly four objects in the array called "potentialPositions".  Why does it think the bounds are only 0..2 ?  It can't be in my DrawAWord method as I put an NSLOG (result not shown above) it is doesn't get called for i = 3.  I am stumped.

Thanks for any answers or hints.

Comment: How about [currentLevel objectAtIndex:levelLink] objectAtIndex:i] - probably this is a reason to crash. Split it into two lines for better debugging.

Comment: You're right.  The problem was the other array and I was trying to be too tricky by using i for both, when I really meant to use the arrays with different indexing.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What

```
[currentLevel objectAtIndex:levelLink]
```

returns? It seems problem is here. Add

```
NSLog(@"%@",[currentLevel objectAtIndex:levelLink]);
```

to see how many elements does it has.

Answer (score 1):

You want to start at 0:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < (choices); i++)
```

Comment: I get that I normally would, but I have a special reason for leaving out 0 at this point.  This part of the code is populating the incorrect choices.  Object 0 is reserved for the position of the correct answer.  I still don't know why it thinks the bounds is 0..2.

Comment: Oh I see, looks like [currentLevel objectAtIndex:levelLink] could be the issue? What is count of levelLink?

Comment: But I give you +1 because combined with Grzegorz you guys got my brain working again.

Comment: Thanks, and yes sometimes answers that aren't exactly correct can help you think about it in a different way. I know I make little mistakes like this all the time.